# Help with a SQL query

Tags: sql

I have been trying different sql queries that do the following:

For all the table entries which have a field that has a field_value in clumn_a of table_1 which equals any field value in column_b of table_2 insert the id of the field in table_2 in id_of_the_other_entry_column of table_1.

However I can only use SQL and not use anything else than a SQL command for that. Is this even possible without the help of another programming language? If so.. any tips?

EDIT:
An example:

```
TableOwner  
id  name
1   SomeCompany
2   SomeOtherCompany

TableContracts
Name               ownerid
NewCompany       Null --> Should remain null after the query
SomeCompany     Null -->Should change to 1 after the query
SomeCompany        Null -->Should change to 1 after the query
SomeOtherCompany   Null -->Should change to 2 after the query
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
update tableContracts t2 set t2.ownerid=t1.id where exists( select t1.id from tableowner t1 where t1.name=t2.Name)
```

Comment: I can't see how this can work: the scope of correlation name `t1` is limited the subquery yet it is being used outside of the subquery.

Answer (score 1):

```
UPDATE
    table_2
SET
    id_of_the_other_entry_column = t1.ID
FROM
    table_2 t2
INNER JOIN
    table_1 t1
ON 
    t1.column_a = t2.column_b
```

**EDIT:**

Just tried this with MySQL, without success.
With MySQL use:

```
UPDATE
    table_2 as t2
SET
    id_of_the_other_entry_column = (SELECT
                                        t1.ID
                                    FROM
                                        table_1 as t1
                                    WHERE
                                        t1.col_a = t2.col_b
                                    )
```

**Importent:**
If table_1 contains more then one row with table_1.col_a equal to table_2.col_b the command will abort.

Comment: But the select will return a set of many different ids since t1.col_a = t2.col_b is true for many different ids.

Comment: **Hint**: If you want to make even more complex operations you don't need to use other languages. You also can create Stored procedure in many sql db's. MySQL: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: @marco: to solve problem with multiple return rows just add `LIMIT 1` (MySQL) or `AND rownum = 1` (Oracle) to the end of subquery

Comment: @Alexander Malakhov: in this case he doesn't get the a reference from table_2 to all table_1 rows.   @marco: with one-to-many relation, the relation id must set to table_1, not to table_2

Comment: @Wowa: as I understood question, it OK

Comment: @Alexander Malakhov: i know, you got +1 from me, because without more info about for what he wants the id in table_2 but not in table_1, LIMIT 1 is the only way to get the SQL working